# Javah work some class, but doesnt work some class

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native, javah

There are a alot of questions about javah, but I couldnt find any solution for my issue for 3 day.

My java file work normally and no error.
I copied my java file "I2CInterface.java" to "jdk/bin" directory.
Then "javac I2CInterface.java" the I2CInterface.class created  succesfully.
But "javah -jni I2CInterface" is not work the header file cant created. The error is "class not found" I try with classpath but not work. I set my environtmental and add path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin. No work. 
That is interesting **javah work on some class and it can create header**. But on this class and some class not work.

The problem is about java file?  My java file below.

```
package com.multitek.ipintercomflatunit;


public class I2CInterface { 

private static native int i2cwrite(byte[] data);    
private static native byte[] i2cread(int data_len);

public static int write(byte[] data) {
    return(i2cwrite(data));
}
public static byte[] read(int data_len) {
    return(i2cread(data_len));
}

static 
{
    System.loadLibrary("i2cinterface");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the class is in a package, say `xxx`, the correct command line will be

```
javah xxx.I2CInterface
```

> I copied my java file "I2CInterface.java" to "jdk/bin" directory

Why? There's no need to do that. Don't pollute the Java installation directory with your own stuff. Leave it where it was and compile it there. Adjust your PATH if necessary so you can execute the JDK tools.

Comment: Path setting is set but with some class javah work and create header. For this class javah give error

Comment: So answer the implied question. Is it in a package? And if so, have you carried out the instructions in my answer?

Comment: I am so sorry. I already try it and again now  "javah -jni com.example.I2CInterface" not work and I entry project folder on command line try again "javah -jni com.example.I2CInterface" not work The problem can be about my java code.

Comment: And is that the package that it's in? and is the .class file in `./com/example/I2CInterface.class` relative to where you are? You need to realize that the information you're providing here is completely inadequate. "Not work" is neither a problem description nor even English.

Comment: Yes I2CInterface.class is in package. Error Couldnt class file for com.example.I2CInterface.

Comment: That's not the error at all. Try again. Java error messages aren't as illerate as that. And you've only answered one of several questions I asked.

Comment: When I delete the **"package com.multitek.ipintercomflatunit;"** from java file. Javah dont give any error and created header. But I dont know, can it be an error.

Comment: If you have 'package com.multitek.ipintercomflatunit' in your Java file, why aren't you specifying ***that*** package name to the javah tool? Surely it is obvious that the correct command is 'javah com.multitek.ipintercomflatunit.I2CInterface'?

Comment: I try all this below but I cant,                                                 javah -jni com.multitek.ipintercomflatunit.I2CInterface,                         javah  com.multitek.ipintercomflatunit.I2CInterface,                     javah -jni I2CInterface,                                               javah -classpath <mayclassPath>  I2CInterface,                     javah -classpath <mayclassPath> com.multitek.ipintercomflatunit.I2CInterface,

Comment: The first one should work provided that ./com/multitek/ipintercomflatunit/I2CInterface.class exists below your current directory.

Comment: I try your last suggestion
I give this error, Exception in thread “main” java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class    Maybe javac create faulty class. is it possible?                            Thanks a lot EJP you are very kind and patient.

Comment: Let's start again. You must have `./com/multitek/ipintercomflatunit/I2CInterface.java`, where `.` is your current directory. Compile that: `javac com/multitek/ipintercomflatunit/I2CInterface.java`. Then: `javah -jni com.multitek.ipintercomflatunit.I2CInterface.`

Comment: Ok, my project directory: 'C:\Users\cumali\Desktop\eclipse\workspaceAndroid\Deneme_I2C\IpIntercomFlatUnit\src\com\multitek\ipintercomflatunit' , mypackage: 'com.multitek.ipintercomflatunit' , and I compile that: 'javac C:\Users\cumali\Desktop\eclipse\workspaceAndroid\Deneme_I2C\IpIntercomFlatUnit\src\com\multitek\ipintercomflatunit\I2CInterface.java' ,  created 'I2CInterface.class' is in '.com\multitek\ipintercomfltunit\' folder. Also there is my java files folder.Then I entry that folder '.src\com\multitek\ipintercomflatunit' at command prompt. So 'I2CInterface.class'  is in there.

Comment: As you say I use 'javah -jni com.multitek.ipintercomflatunit.I2CInterface'  Error: could not class file for "com.multitek.ipintercomflatunit.I2CInterface".
I loose my sense.  If I delete 'package com.multitek.ipintercomflatunit;' from java file then javah created header. Why  the javah deny package name?

Comment: I asked my problem at community oracle. I put there some photo and more detailed about this.[link](https://community.oracle.com/message/12549439#12549439)

Comment: Please do it *exactly* the way I said.

Comment: I give little info about my problem. If the java file have a package like this **package com.xxx.yyy **  javah couldnt create header. If java file dont have package name Javah create header succesfully. Also My computer win8_64  jdk1.8.0, I worked with eclipse and my project is an Android project.

Comment: I'm still waiting for you to try it my way. If you're not prepared to take the advice you're given here, I don't know why you're posting here at all.

Comment: You misunderstanding me I am sorry.When I saw your advice I tried your way immediately. And then i write the result on my message. My message is up it start "Ok my project directory.."                            I surrender no longer. Lastly I try win7. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: In the message starting "OK my project directory" you give a series of commands which are completely different from the commands I had just given you in the previous message beginning "let's start again". You're trying everything *except* what I'm telling you. It's pointless to continue with this.

Comment: Problem solved by oracle forum. The problem was classpath. **Classpath was project's src folder.**  Javah can create header succesfully now. it was my fault I could not explain my problem clearly to you.Thanks to all.

Comment: You shouldn't normally have to adjust your CLASSPATH at all. I haven't done that since about 1998. '.' is sufficient for most cases including  this one. Setting it to a source directory doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: I am new JNI and Ndk.maybe it caused win8 or jdk1.8. I realized that set the classpath is requisite.